# Connect Azure Web Service to Azure VM SQL Server DB in Virtual Network

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure, virtual-machine

**What I'm trying to do**

I have a web application that I'm trying to test out on the Azure platform. My plan is to put the asp.net mvc application on an Azure Web Service and host SQL Server on an Azure VM.

I have it setup now such that the web app can successfully talk to the SQL Server DB using the public IP address. But I want the latency between the two to be minimized as much as possible, so I'm assuming (maybe incorrectly?) that it'd be better to have them both on a virtual network. I'd also like to be able to access SQL Server from my local development computer via SSMS and Visual Studio to do schema compares and changes from VS.

I'd like to have the web services in a `frontend` subnet and the db server in a `backend` subnet, similar to what is [depicted here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-overview/).

Note: I am NOT a networking guy...but a developer, so a lot of this is a bit foreign to me.

**What I've done so far**

1. I have created an Azure VM running SQL Server, that is assigned to a virtual network that was asked to create during the VM setup. `xxx-vnet/default`
2. I've created the web service
3. When I try to assign my web service to this virtual network, it is greyed out and the icon popup message states: `The virtual network has no gateway.`
4. I added a VPN gateway, now when I try to add the web service to the vnet, it is still greyed out and says, `Gateway does not have any point to site addresses.`

**Questions**

1. Am I even correct assuming that putting the web service and vm in the same vnet will reduce latency?
2. Do I need a VPN gateway as part of this vnet?
3. Do I need point to site addresses?
4. What else do I need to configure to get these both in the same vnet?

Answer (score 0):

To answer some of your questions:

2. Yes, you need the gateway for the VNet connection
3. Yes, you need some addresses in the point-to-site pool because the Web App needs at least one
4. That should be enough, but you can find a complete guide here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/

For the performance, I don't have any actual numbers. The main reason people do these connections is so you can restrict the connections into the VMs to only from within that point-to-site subnet within the virtual network. Otherwise you have to make them publicly accessible. If you want better performance and VNet integration, you would need to use an App Service Environment which is kind of a premium offering. That one is put into a VNet, unlike the connection that can be done in App Service.